# Streaming different MP3 files using Ezstream and Icecast

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I am trying to stream two MP3 files to Icecast using Ezstream and the stream should run in web browsers. The files I am testing with were downloaded as webm and converted to MP3 using `ffmpeg`. They have the same channels count, same bitrate and same sample rate but different duration.

My setup: the Ezstream xml configuration file is set to stream MP3 and a program playlist is used to identify what is the next file to be streamed, and no encoders or decoders are used. When I start streaming I save the process ID of the Ezstream process (using the `-p` argument), and then I use the command `kill -10 $(cat currentpid)` with `currentpid` as the file containing the process ID so Ezstream executes the playlist program to get the next file name and skips the current file to play the next one. Basically I am just switching between `1.mp3` and `2.mp3`.

---

The problem is that on Chrome web browser, when I switch between the two files the player (default HTML5 player) will suddenly stop (sometimes I can switch multiple times before it happens and sometimes it happens quickly) and the error `PIPELINE_ERROR_DECODE` is what I find when I access `player.error` in JavaScript. Although Firefox handles the change and continues the stream normally, I am convinced that Firefox here is the exception, that it is not a bug in Chrome (in my case), and that there is something wrong with my setup that needs to be fixed to support other browsers.

Doing the same using `mpv` player, I get the following errors but the audio keeps streaming normally (sometimes it takes multiple switches before it happens just like in Chrome):

```
[ffmpeg/audio] mp3float: big_values too big
[ffmpeg/audio] mp3float: Error while decoding MPEG audio frame.
Error decoding audio.
```

I tried using MP3 encoder and decoder I copied from the Ezstream example files (`lame` and `madplay`) but the problem still existed.

I am not sure if the problem is basic and I cannot see it or it is more complicated. Also I do not have a problem if I need to use other format than MP3 to fix that issue, as long as that format is supported by Ezstream and Icecast.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed? I am having problems with mp3 as well

Comment: @DroidChris I don't remember finding a fix for this unfortunately and I didn't continue what I was trying to do at the time. Depending on your use case, you might find `mpd` (has built-in HTTP output setting) or other services a good replacement

Comment: what is mpd? Can you point me to a link on that please?

Comment: @DroidChris sure, `mpd` is a music player server, here are the links: https://www.musicpd.org/ (official website) and https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Music_Player_Daemon (more details and configurations). It should be good if it can replace `ezstream` for your use case and you'll find different GUI and CLI clients to control the server. I have to note that I haven't tried `ezstream` again since posting the question, so I'm not sure if newer versions address this or whether it was a bug or a misconfiguration on my side

Comment: OK I got it working with MP3. I will update below.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I did get this to work. Almost all was there. Some sampling rates were off and my radio station tuning was not good for the area. Here is the command line command I used:

```
rtl_fm -f 107.3M -g 50 -M fm -s 200k -E deemp | sox -r 200k -t raw -e s -b 16 -c 1 -V6 - -t mp3 -| ezstream -v -v -c /etc/icecast2/ezstream.xml > /dev/null &
```

And here is my ezstream.xml file changes that I did to make this work:

[image]

I just changed the output to .mp3, the sampling rate to 48000 and 24 bit encoding.